# detect phone call made by 3rd party apps

Tags: java, android, skype, phone-call, recording

I'm a new android developer, and i'm trying to make a call recorder for skype/viber/ any other 3rd party app that have phone calls,
i tried to use AccessibilityService to detect the incoming phone call from the notifictaion bar but that why realy isnt usfull because i cant know if the user answer the call, and when he finish it..
something else i tried to do, is to use getCurrentTopActivity when i got AccessibilityService to get the call activity by

[image: help]

but that didnt work.. got "com.google.android.launcher.GEL"
for
        `Log.d(TAG, "correct Activity=" + ar.topActivity.getClassName());`
and anywhy couldnt get any update about the call..

for example, this is an app that record skype and viber calls.. trying to make something similar
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.steadycallrecorder

(skype is just example, i know that there is skyper API but i dont want to use it.)
ty from advance, and sorry if there is any grammer mistakes.. not a english speaker :)

Comment: You might be able to get something that works for a specific app (ex Skype), but not for any app that makes a voice call.  Any network request could be voice data.

Comment: i want something that works for a specific app.. can explain how can i do it in skype?

Comment: @Didi78 did you get this to work?